# DatePickerDialog shows e.g. M plus integer instead of month name

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

`DatePickerDialog` display `M01` instead of `January` for example...

This is my code:

```
@OnClick(R.id.dateTextView)
public void onDateTextViewClick(View view) {
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            mDateListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    dialog.show();
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mYear = arg1;
        mMonth = arg2;
        mDay = arg3;
        showDate();
    }
};
```

How can I change it?

Comment: facing same issue showing only above nougat  !!  any solution found ?

Answer (score 2):

You wrongly set your local value. Something like this

```
// Don't copy past this  
Locale locale = new Locale("","");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Instead use proper language code and country code.
eg:-

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en","GB");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just pass month no and you will get Month Name**

```
 public String getMonth(int month) {
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
}
```

Comment: Please tell us details how it work try to pass date picker but not worked ...explain how u use this method

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getDate(EditText editText) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    // date picker dialog
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(CustomerProfileActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    selectedDate = year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;

                    editText.setText(selectedDate);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Just pass "Locale.getDefault()" in Calendar.getInstance